# Splitting dataframe in smaller dataframe when value in column match and export them to excel fromat (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory, export-to-excel

I have a dataframe A. I need to divide it in smaller dataframes with matching street names.

Here is the dataframe I have:

| id | Location_name | Street_Number | Street_name | Object_needed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | McDonald's | 4 | Rue de Hollande | C400/P200 |
| 2 | Hollande | 175 | Rue de Hollande | Porte socle simple S20 |
| 3 | Stade | 197 | Rue des potiers | CCPI S20 6980138 |
| 4 | King Jouet | 33 | Rue des potiers | Coffret CCPI CIBE Mono |
| 5 | CARIBBEAN CLEANING | 6 | Galisbay | Coffret CCPI CIBE Mono |

The result I'm trying to have:

Data Frame 1 :

| id | Location_name | Street_Number | Street_name | Object_needed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | McDonald's | 4 | Rue de Hollande | C400/P200 |
| 2 | Hollande | 175 | Rue de Hollande | Porte socle simple S20 |

Data Frame 2:

| id | Location_name | Street_Number | Street_name | Object_needed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Stade | 197 | Rue des potiers | CCPI S20 6980138 |
| 4 | King Jouet | 33 | Rue des potiers | Coffret CCPI CIBE Mono |

DataFrame 3 :

| id | Location_name | Street_Number | Street_name | Object_needed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | CARIBBEAN CLEANING | 6 | Galisbay | Coffret CCPI CIBE Mono |

The goal is to create as many dataframes as there is corresponding street names.

I'm using a groupby:

```
grouper = [g[1] for g in df.groupby(['Street_name'])]
```

Is there a way to name them after the `street_name` they are classing ? Instead of being name `grouper[0]` for the first one but `Rue_de_Hollande` in my example.

Lastly, do you know to export all the dataframe at once to an excel format ?

Comment: Do you want the dataframes in one excel file within different sheets/tabs? Or do you want seperate files for each street?

Comment: @chatax if all the new dataframes could in one excel it would be perfect !

Comment: see my answer for the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your streets in seperate excel sheets in one file, you can use the Pandas ExcelWriter:

```
streets = set(df.Street_name)
with pd.ExcelWriter('all_streets_excel.xlsx', mode='w') as writer:
    for street_name in streets:
        street_df = df[df.loc[:, 'Street_name'] == street_name]
        street_df.to_excel(writer, street_name)
```

Comment: sorry, I thaught I was working for my problem but it only had a single row of street. Like It does not create an exel with every row such as "Data frame 1" in my exemple for "Rue de Hollande". It only had the id 1 row but not the other one (id2).

Comment: Perhaps there is a spelling mistake? Check for whitespace

Comment: Please try again with `mode='w'`

Comment: I was trying it with the previous version of your code, you were write, I had not properely clean my street name column so there was still some whitespace. 
Now I'm trying your new version I have some new issue. 
One line 2 I have this error "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'all_streets_excel.xlsx'" so I manualy create this file In the colob directory. But then I have a new error on the same : "BadZipFile: File is not a zip file". What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I havn't see your other response I was working perfectly with mode=w. Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the pandas.query, and pandas.to_excel methods by creating a list of the unique street names and iterating over in a for loop:

```
streets = df["Street_name"].unique()

for street in streets:
    df_streets = df.query('Street_name == @street')
    df_streets.to_excel(street + '.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response 
Your approach works well too, but I'm trying to acheive it with a loop as my dataframe has a larger amount of rows than my exemple.  

But your method will help me for another problem for sure ;)

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful! I've edited my post to include a method to achieve the same with a loop.

Comment: I think you'll find this achieves exactly what you're looking for ;) If it works on your end I'd really appreciate if you could give it an upvote and accept the answer. I'm starting out here too :)

Comment: Thank you again ! Yes I will

Comment: I would argue that mine is the more simple and effective solution, but whatever works for you I suppose...